# Problem after upgrading 18.04 -> 18.10

Tags: apt, updates, 18.10

yesterday, I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04. to 18.10.
While upgrading there were some errors/warnings which I couldn't remember or copied.
Nevertheless, if I'm `apt update & apt upgrade` right now, I get the following error:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-4.18.0-17-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-17-generic
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/21.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,136 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 321219 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-4.18.0-17-generic_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.18.0-17-generic (4.18.0-17.18) over (4.18.0-17.18~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.18.0-17-generic_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './boot/System.map-4.18.0-17-generic' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.18.0-17-generic_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.18.0-17-generic (4.18.0-17.18) over (4.18.0-17.18~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.18.0-17-generic_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-17-generic' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.18.0-17-generic_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.18.0-17-generic_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

a `uname -a` shows me, that the new kernel is installed:

```
Linux 4.18.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:45:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hence, I'm wondering why apt tries to install 4.18.0-17 packages...

Any thoughts?

edit: nothing unusual in the sources.list

```
root@pumpkin:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-security main restricted universe multiverse

# deb https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main
# deb-src https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the package cache? You can use `sudo apt clean` to clean it and try again.

Comment: @Olimjon yes, I've tried that. Unfortunately it didn't had any effect on my problem.

Comment: Please, edit the question to post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120964/what-means-unable-to-make-backup-link-of-binary-before-installing-new-version or https://www.howtoforge.com/debian-ubuntu-unable-to-make-backup-link-of-usr-bin-sshd-before-installing-new-version-operation-not-permitted. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Links say that it might be wrong attributes set for some reason or corrupt file system. I'd check the file system from a Live USB. And make a backup of your important data if you don't have that already.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to solve my problem:

before upgrading, I just deleted the files which the updater couldn't backup.

```
/boot/System.map-4.18.0-17-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-17-generic
```

even though it didn't feel right to delete files from the boot folder.
But anyways; it worked.